# How to resolve overlapping data from mapped input rows in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React form that involves collecting data from an API and processing it, I fetch the items from an API then map through it to create a form for each object, so my user can input a price. The user is supposed to be able to set the price of multiple items for processing.

My problem is from the search feature, I filter through the objects to implement a search feature. However, if I set the price of the first item, then filter the list so the first item is gone. The price of the first item remains in the first `input`, so the prices appear mismatched.

They aren't mismatched though as the object that I am using to record the data is still accurate, it just looks very confusing visually.

I have recreated my error in [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-chatterjee-mduqq?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you never set the value of your price input field.

```js
<input
  type="number"
  onChange={(e) => handleFormData(item.name, e.target.value)}
/>
```

As there is no value passed to the input it will lose it's value once it is unmounted. That's what is happening with you. When it unmounts it lose it's value.

**Solve to the problem**

```js
<input
  type="number"
  value={formData[item.name]}
  onChange={(e) => handleFormData(item.name, e.target.value)}
/>
```

But please use unique identifier to identify other than the name. Because it might conflict. And it is conflicting for `sarah`

code link - https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-satoshi-q1g52?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I just tried that and updated the sandbox... it didn't work.

Comment: There are also some warning in the code. I assume you understand those and this is for demo. Like key, value without onChange etc

Comment: The issue is that I already did that in my actual code, the sandbox is just me trying to recreate the error. 
But it seems there is something that I am not capturing.

Comment: If the solve is not working then the problem might be in the identifier or the implementation is not same as sandbox

Comment: Yes, sorry I don't believe it's key. I tried that in the sandbox. @moshfiqrony 's answer worked, but because of the size of my actual codebase, I am having issues applying it.

Comment: I am not saying about the react key. What I am referring is the object key

Comment: @g-moniava appreciate you, but I think what he was describing is not a unique react key issue. Think about this. When a component is unmounted then key is not a fact anymore.